# Setting a 12 hour Time for javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function showTime() { let today = new Date(), hour = today.getHours();

hour = hour % 12 || 12;
}

showTime();
```

I understand the part `hour % 12(Ex: 13 % 12 = 1)` But what I don't get is the `|| 12` part.

Comment: `||` is the [OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) operator.
What it means: If `hour % 12` return 0 then `hour` will be equal to 12, not 0.
Because `0 || 12` return `0`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

Comment: Now i get it, Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
let hour = 0
hour = hour % 12 || 12;
```

whenever `hour % 12` this expression results into `0`,  this will give `12` as an answer

Comment: Just a small tip - you can try js code in crome itself and see outputs on the go. right-click on the window -> inspect  -> select console and try js expression there

Answer (score 0):

Like *Thibault Husté* sayed it will return instead of 0 the 12.

> But this is probably not allways what you want because `[0, ..., 23]`
> should result in `[0, ... 12, 1, ..., 11]` but you will get `[12, 1, ... ,12, 1, ... ,11]`.
>  The day starts with `00:00 - 00:59` and not with `12:00 - 12.59`.

So this should do it.

```js
for (hour=0; hour<24; hour++) {
    res = hour % 12 || ((hour==12) ? 12: 0);
    console.log(res);
}
```